# ExtJs How to order a Store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm using a `Ext.data.Store` to save data temporarily. When save the data by default the store puts the elements like a tail. Is there any way to save store data like a stack?

Answer (score 3):

there is a method `sort` for this https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sort]